# Obtaining exact output values of SMO classification, before clearly demarcating them into classes

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, weka, smo

While running the SMO classifier in weka, if I have inputted my training labels as 0 and 5, (A binary set), then while running the classifier model on test data, are the outputs some decimal values between 0 and 5 which get distinctly classified into the two binary labels at a latter step, or are there no intermediate decimal values?

If they exist, how to obtain these intermediate decimal values?

(Eg, In the above model, does the smo/svm classifier assign values like 1 , 2, 3 and 4, or some other decimal/float value within the given range and then these get appropriately grouped under the 0 and 5 value classes).

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of "label value" in classification. Label is just an identifier, not comparable object, which is assigned to particular instances in your problem. "0" and "5" could be as well "lion" and "elephant".

For SVM in particular (WEKA done a horrible thing to the scientific community by making people call SVM an SMO, only beacuse this is the solver algorithm used inside...) every labeling is transformed into "-1" and "+1". Internally, SVM does have a concept of support as it will linearly project your data point, thus obtaing a value from whole R (-inf, +inf), and assigns label according to a sign. This, in very rough sense, is kind of model's certainty (however not calibrated in any probabilsitic sense, thus "0.01" does not mean anything besides "less than 0.02", but one cannot even say that 0.01 is as many times more uncertain than a point with 0.02 , as there is no reasonable scaling of these values.

In "pure" weka  there is `classifier.distributionForInstance()` which returns these values. In weka explorer on the `classify` tab, click on `More options...` and tick `Output predictions` to get them.

Comment: If I have an input of two classes in the classifier, then will the output predictions only provide values for those points which are nearer to the separating SVM hyperplane? 

My classifier seems to give only 0.444, 0.555 values apart from a 0.